# Making a property only set-able by a specific method

Tags: c#, properties, enums

I'm trying to make a chemistry equation balancer thingy. For that I made a class Element:

```
class Element
{
    public elemEnum ElemType {get; set;}
    public double Amount {get; set;} // How many atoms of this type in the formula
}
```

*`elemEnum` is an Enum of all the chemical elements.

I wanted to make the `set` for `ElemType` parse a string to the enumeration, but since `set` can only take in values of the same type as `value` I decided to add a method:

```
public void SetElemType(string type)
{
    this.ElemType = (elemEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(elemEnum), type);
}
```

Is there an option to have the `ElemType` property be only set-able by the `SetElemType` method without having to make it `private` and adding a `GetElemType` method?

Comment: There are private getters/setters in C#. `public elemEnum ElemType { get; private set; }`. Did you try using that?

Comment: For your question, i don't think its possible to use the auto setter/getter methods to accept an different type then the type of the variable. You could set the setter of ElemType to private to make sure it can only be set form within the class.

Maybe of topic, but type names in C# should be in pascal case, meaning "elemEnum" should be "ElemEnum"

Comment: Ok, maybe you can do it, what's purpose of such property?

Comment: The common solution is to use a private setter, as shown in Caramiriel's comment. Your property may still be set by other members of your class, but that shouldn't be an issue since you have full control over your class's implementation.

Comment: @EdoPost I did not know there are private set/getters. And my bad about the capitalization, I'm kinda new to this and I will take notice to it in the future.

Comment: @ItamarReif as you can see in Caramiriel's comment you can specify a visibility modifier to the setter or getter (or both, although they you could better set the whole property). If you set the set method to private you can ensure that that class is the only one who can write the value of the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the most obvious solution from the comments has not been written as an answer:

## Use a [private setter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx).

```
class Element
{
    public ElemEnum ElemType {get; private set;}
    public double Amount {get; set;}

    public void SetElemType(string type)
    {
        this.ElemType = (ElemEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(ElemEnum), type);
    }
}
```

This way, `ElemType` can only be set from within your own class.

Comment: I'm not so sure that making it a private setter is the best solution, if the goal is to make a pro arty thats only settable by the method, then only making it private won't do it. since any method in that class can edit the value. Therefor i'd say that Kapol's answer is a better solution for this problem.

Comment: @EdoPost I doubt OP is trying to protect it from methods of his own class, rather from outside manipulation.

Comment: @EdoPost Yeah, Rotem is correct. The class probably isn't even gonna hold anything other than the properties, constructor and the method.

Answer (score 0):

As already was pointed, you can use `private setter`, alternatively you can use `readonly` property with `public getter` that works with field and method to modify this field :

```
class Element
{
   private elemEnum _elemType;

   public elemEnum ElemType { get { return _elemType; } }

   public void SetElemType(string type) 
   {
      this._elemType = (elemEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(elemEnum), type);
   }

   public double Amount {get; } // How many atoms of this type in the formula
}
```

While it is practically the same as property with `private setter` it uses a slightly different approach...

Well if you really want to allow only one(!) method to change value you can use reflection and add class that envelopes your enum :

```
class MyElemSetter
{
    private readonly elemEnum elem;

    public MyElemSetter(elemEnum e, Action helperAction)
    {
        MethodInfo callingMethodInfo = helperAction.Method;

        if (helperAction.Method.Name.Contains("<SetElemType>")) elem = e;
    }

    public static implicit operator elemEnum(MyElemSetter e)
    {
        return e.elem;
    }
}

class Element
{
    private MyElemSetter _elemType;

    public elemEnum ElemType { get { return _elemType; } }

    public void SetElemType(string type)
    {
        this._elemType = new MyElemSetter((elemEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(elemEnum), type), () => { });
    }

    public double Amount { get; set; } // How many atoms of this type in the formula
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> without having to make it private

Well, you could create a workaround solution by adding a `bool` field to your class and modifying the property a little bit.

```
class Element
{
    private bool _elemCanBeSet = false;
    private elemNum _elemType;

    public elemEnum ElemType
    {
        get { return _elemType; }
        set { if (_elemCanBeSet) _elemType = value; }
    }

    public double Amount {get; set;} // How many atoms of this type in the formula

    public void SetElemType(string type)
    {
        _elemCanBeSet = true;
        this.ElemType = (elemEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(elemEnum), type);
        _elemCanBeSet = false;
    }
}
```

This solution may confuse the developer using your class, because setting the property will have no effect. It is **much** better to use a private setter for your task, as stated by others. I just wanted to show an alternative approach.

Comment: Why would you prefer this over an existing language construct - private setters?

Comment: @Rotem The OP pretty much asked to avoid the existing language construct. I think your comment should be one on the question, not on this answer.

Comment: @Rotem I don't prefer it. I just wanted to show how it's possible to achieve what OP wants without making the property private (see the citation at the beginning of my post).

Comment: @hvd The OP asked how they could avoid making the entire property private (thus having to supply an additional manual getter and setter). OP was unaware of private setters.

Comment: @Rotem Which the OP cleared up in the comments later. Right. The actual question is a bit vague and without the comments on the question, I interpreted it the same way Kapol did in this answer.

Comment: @hvd I did not understand what was unclear or how OPs comment changes anything. Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: Lol what if we add another method that changes `_elemCanBeSet` to `true` and then modifies value with no problem at all ? How is this going to help in this case ?

Comment: @Fabjan If we are designing the class, why would we ever want to create such a method? I'd rather not shoot my own foot like that.

Comment: @Kapol If we are designing the class, why do we need to protect the property from changes inside the class?